# why drastic performance degradation when running a command as different user

Tags: c, linux, bash, redhat, su

i have a hello world `C` example `./a.out`

Now i measured execution time using `time` for below commands

```
time  ./a.out
Hello World
real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s

time runuser -l root -c './a.out'
real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.011s

time su -s /bin/bash -c "./a.out" root 
Hello World
real    0m0.080s ---> 80 times slower
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.071s
```

Why is the third command `80` times slower than the first command?

Environment -- `Redhat 7`

Comment: Why would you expect starting a new account session, and in the second case a bash instance within that session, to take no time?

Comment: Also, runuser already starts `/bin/sh` to invoke a command passed with `-c`.  Part of what you're measuring is the performance difference between `/bin/sh` and `bash`.

Comment: Incidentally, I'd expect `sudo -u root ./a.out` to potentially be a little better -- still has all the PAM overhead, but at least it's not running any shells. That's configuration-dependant, though -- if `sudo` is doing a bunch of directory lookups while evaluating its configuration, all bets are off.

Comment: @charles sudo -u perform better... but we can pass the command as string like in runuser....is there a way to pass command as string to sudo -u

Comment: Passing the command "as a string" is what requires a shell to interpret, and that's what makes it slow. (Also insecure, if any parts of that string are user-driven; think about running `./setpasswd "$user" "$password"` -- if `password` contains `$(rm -rf /*)` and you're passing the command through a shell after it's expanded, you're in for a bad day). So... yes, you could use `sudo` with a string, either by using an argument such as `-i` or explicitly naming a shell on the command line, but not without giving up the performance advantages.

Comment: If the reason you want a string is to make it easier to build up a command line in your shell script's logic, by the way, I suggest looking into bash arrays for a better way to do that; see also BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: i am trying to run a generate shell command from java using runtime.exec

Comment: There's a `Runtime.exec()` form that lets you pass an array. Use it.

Comment: ...specifically: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File) <- no shell, so you don't need to worry about shell-specific vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: I say this as someone who's audited Java programs *written specifically for process orchestration* and found shell injection bugs: Getting the corner cases right is in all probability harder than you think. Don't risk it.

Comment: @charles is there a repo available of "Java programs written specifically for process orchestration"... that will be helpfull to start with

Comment: You might start with Rundeck. See https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/298 for a fun time.

Comment: ...that said, Rundeck does shell quoting (and thus had the above bug in the first place) because it's running commands over SSH, and running a command over SSH *always* involves a remote shell. If you're just running local commands, you don't need that mess at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the second and third command, the `time` command also times the launch of `runuser`, `su` and `bash`, which takes some time as well.

It shouldn't make so many difference if you do:

```
$ runuser -l root -c 'time ./a.out'
```

and:

```
$ su -s /bin/bash -c "time ./a.out" root
```